# WPF binding: DataGrid showing empty rows instead of my data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have created a simple WPF application where I want to import data from an excel sheet, perform some custom actions and export to an online calendar. To have grip on the number of items exported to the online agenda I want to create a datagrid where I can filter and select items which I want to export.

I have the wpf grid as follows:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridAgendaItems" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Margin="0,0,0,61" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Date}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tijd" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Time}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Locatie" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Location}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"  Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Omschrijving" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The code behind (stripped for reviewing and help purpose:

```
namespace ExcelToCalendar
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ICollection<Excel.AgendaRow> AgendaItems;
        ...
        private void BtnConfirmColumns_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...

            AgendaItems = new List<Excel.AgendaRow>();
            foreach(var row in Rows)
            {
                ...
                Excel.AgendaRow tmpAgendaItem = new()
                {
                    Date = row.Columns[dateColumn].ToString(),
                    Title = row.Columns[titleColumn].ToString()
                };
                ...
                AgendaItems.Add(tmpAgendaItem);
            }

            dataGridAgendaItems.ItemsSource = AgendaItems;
        }
    }
}
```

and the excel class

```
 public class Excel
    {
        ...

        public class AgendaRow
        {
            public int Id;
            public required string Date;
            public string? Time;
            public string? Location;
            public string? Description;
            public required string Title;
            public bool IsSelected;
        }
    }
```

When I run the application the datagrid shows the correct number of Rows, but all columns are empty. What is going wrong? Tried a lot of stuf for hours now and not getting somewhere, please help.

Comment: As well as  changing these to properties, you should implement inotifypropertychanged. If you don't then there will likely be memory leaks. Doesn't matter if you're not changing property values.

Comment: WPF-Binding Paths refer to **Properties**- Your Excel.AgendaRow class just exposes **Fields**. So your Celltemplate bindings don't work, but the itemssource it self is bound (that is why the row count matches)
As @YasinARLI pointed out, you need to rework your class layout a little to make it expose properties rather than fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue might be related to the way you've defined your AgendaRow class. In WPF, when you bind data to a DataGrid, it relies on properties, not fields. Here's how you can modify your AgendaRow class to use properties:

```
public class Excel
{
    // ...

    public class AgendaRow
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```